# Ubuntu main user missing

Tags: login, users, system-settings

[As pointed out in another post, I had to setup a new user account after a crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246392/ubuntu-20-04-crash-causes-system-reset), that helped me to log back in. After reboot I could select "Not listed?" and login to my old account. When I go to account, I exclusively see the new account, not the old one, that I am logged in with. Removal was not possible.

**Update**:
Now I removed the new user via `sudo deluser newuser`; after reboot I have to type in my username in order to logon. In the gnome menu settings it tells me: **"No Users Found"**

[Image of the Settings in Gnome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ux4w.png)

Comment: What is the numeric UID of your user (e.g. the output of `id -u`, or the output of `getent passwd olduser`)?

Comment: uid, gid are 1000. In the passwd file there is no other user than the one I created. But I still have to type in my username everytime on logon.